# How to find shared resource allocation while doing capacity planning - Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

How to find shared resource allocation while doing capacity planning.
eg: If QA persons is shared across all the teams,while doing capacity planning are there any indication to find allocated hours.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to find shared resource allocation while doing capacity planning - Azure Devops

I am afraid there is no such out of way to find shared resource allocation while doing capacity planning. But I think your request is reasonable.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

**Besides**, there is a extension [Team Capacity Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfc.team-capacity), which provides and overview of the assigned capacity of individual team members across multiple teams within a team project. You can check if it could resolve your request.

Comment: Thanks Leo..
I have post a request as a suggestions
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1133806/show-allocated-hours-for-the-resources-while-doing.html